# Mumble-Django doesn't render correctly after 12.04 to 14.04 server upgrade

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, server, upgrade

I recently ran the upgrade on my server to go from 12.04 to 14.04. I had a couple problems but have gotten almost all of them sorted. One thing that's still hanging me up is the rendering of the mumble-django administration page. After the update, going to my admin page I get an incorrectly rendered page as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hWQo.png).

Everything appears to be working correctly it's just a matter of it being a little difficult to understand how things are grouped when it shows up like this.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect this is because the default versions of Django in 12.04 and 14.04 are two years apart. You've gone from 1.3 to 1.6. There are some significant changes:

- [1.4 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/)
- [1.5 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/)
- [1.6 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/)

You need to pay particular notice to the "Backwards incompatible changes" section in each of these release notes. Most won't apply but some will.

I suspect the big thing affecting you is the change of how Static media is referenced. That's all the problem is, it can't find the Admin CSS and Javascript that's shipped with Django.

If you're not a Python/Django programmer (I am, so sorry if I've jumped in with both feet), your Mumble site basically needs updating to modern Django conventions. Either push this up the stack to its maintainer or jump in and learn some Django.

Comment: Don't worry, you didn't jump in too deep too quickly. I know just enough about how the web front-end stuff works that I was assuming it was in that general area. Unfortunately I'm not a Python or Django coder but I will definitely so some reporting. Thanks for the response!

Comment: You could probably jerry-rig this by aliasing `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/` under `/static/` on the web server configuration. That will obviously conflict with any existing `/static/` definition so if you already have one of those, just copy the contents into yours. Also check the page source to see where it's requesting the admin CSS from. That should let you line things up.

Comment: I did find there was a newer version of mumble-django proposed for Utopic so I downloaded and installed those files. It did clear up one or two errors that had popped up but didn't stop its functioning. Unfortunately, though, the rendering is still broken. Going to submit a bug report to the maintainer. Thanks again for the help.